# Node creation or apperance at run time in Omnet (INET)

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I need to create a node at run time, with similar parameters as the other nodes. For that I am creating a dynamic node in ned file as:-

```
host_send4: meshnode {
        parameters:
            @dynamic;
            @display("p=1000,535;r=200,green;i=device/smallrouter");
}
```

To implement this node in C++ file, I add this code:-

```
    cModuleType *meshnode1 = cModuleType::get("inet.networklayer.manetrouting.PASER.meshnode");
    cModule *mod = meshnode1->createScheduleInit("host_send4", this);
    cDisplayString& dispstr =  mod->getDisplayString();
    dispstr.parse("p=1000,535;r=200,green;i=device/smallrouter");

    mod->buildInside();
    mod->scheduleStart(simTime()+5*beaconInterval);
```

But I am not able to build it properly. I think I am in need of any example on this. Can anybody help me to point out an example in INETMANET of mixim or any other oment framework, where this functionality is already implemented. 
Thanks for your help.

I have also though of creating a node statically, which would appear in simulation at later point of time. Is it possible and is there any example with runtime appearance and disappearance of node in INET or other OMNET framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OMNeT++ User Manual has a [section](http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec186) dedicated to this. According to this you don't need `buildInside()` and `scheduleStart()` when using `createScheduleInit()`.

An example how this is performed can be seen in the Veins framework - more precisely in the [TraCIScenarioManager](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L287). The important lines for you are probably:

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();
if (!parentmod) error("Parent Module not found");

cModuleType* nodeType = cModuleType::get(type.c_str());
if (!nodeType) error("Module Type \"%s\" not found", type.c_str());

cModule* mod = nodeType->create(name.c_str(), parentmod, nodeVectorIndex, nodeVectorIndex);
mod->finalizeParameters();
mod->getDisplayString().parse(displayString.c_str());
mod->buildInside();
mod->scheduleStart(simTime() + updateInterval);
```

Comment: Thanks @floxyz , I need to write only  `cModule *mod = meshnode1->create("host_send4", this);` . And thanks for the example, here I can find some functionalities atleast.

Comment: Thanks @floxyz Now I am able to get the node. You were correct. I needed the parent module where I want to show this node and I tried to put it the same module, which was an error. So the parent module the actual ned file where I want to show my node .